# Quadratic Probing Load Factor Must be 0.5?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, theory

I understand the definition of Load Factor and how Quadratic Probing works.  But what happens in the case where quadratic probing cannot find an empty slot for a new element?

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing:

> In the case of quadratic probing, with the exception of the triangular
>   number case for a power-of-two-sized hash table[2], there is no
>   guarantee of finding an empty cell once the table gets more than half
>   full, or even before the table gets half full if the table size is not
>   prime.

Does this mean that Load Factor should always be 0.5 for a Hash Table that uses Quadratic Probing?

What is the proof of this claim?

Comment: I think you mean 0.5 should be the _largest allowable_ load factor (for prime-sized tables with simple squaring for the probe distance). But that's not necessarily true. Quadratic probing fails only _sometimes_ when the table is over half full. So you can get some benefit by being lazy in deciding when to grow. For example, do it when the average number of probes to find a free spot exceeds a threshold or wait until no spot can be found.

Comment: Clearly that claim does not apply to power of two sized tables that use the triangle number series for probing, as is specifically singled out in that quote as well.